# I have table with 25 rows and 25 columns. The entries and values within table are long. Any suggestions on how to fit it in one page

Tags: tables, landscape

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \Rtext{Austria} & \Rtext{Belgium} & \Rtext{Bulgaria} & \Rtext{Croatia} & \Rtext{Cyprus} & \Rtext{Czech Republic} & \Rtext{Estonia} & \Rtext{Finland} & \Rtext{France} & \Rtext{Germany} & \Rtext{Greece} & \Rtext{Hungary} & \Rtext{Ireland} & \Rtext{Italy} & \Rtext{Latvia} & \Rtext{Lithuania} & \Rtext{Luxembourg} & \Rtext{Netherlands} & \Rtext{Poland} & \Rtext{Portugal} & \Rtext{Romania} & \Rtext{Slovakia} & \Rtext{Slovenia} & \Rtext{Spain} & \Rtext{Sweden} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Austria & $1$ & $0.118$ & $0.077$ & $0.250$ & $0.133$ & $0.125$ & $0.167$ & $0.077$ & $0.133$ & $0.167$ & $0.143$ & $0.214$ & $0.111$ & $0.182$ & $0.083$ & $0.222$ & $0.333$ & $0.167$ & $0.133$ & $0.222$ & $0.200$ & $0.077$ & $0.167$ & $0.133$ & $0.154$ \\ 
Belgium & $0.118$ & $1$ & $0.133$ & $0.125$ & $0.176$ & $0.235$ & $0.133$ & $0.214$ & $0.227$ & $0.240$ & $0.125$ & $0.250$ & $0.083$ & $0.167$ & $0.231$ & $0.077$ & $0.154$ & $0.412$ & $0.250$ & $0.190$ & $0.174$ & $0.133$ & $0.133$ & $0.276$ & $0.200$ \\ 
Bulgaria & $0.077$ & $0.133$ & $1$ & $0.300$ & $0.250$ & $0.067$ & $0.200$ & $0.200$ & $0.114$ & $0.083$ & $0.222$ & $0.154$ & $0.143$ & $0.121$ & $0.222$ & $0.125$ & $0.250$ & $0.118$ & $0.071$ & $0.053$ & $0.100$ & $0.200$ & $0.200$ & $0.103$ & $0.083$ \\ 
Croatia & $0.250$ & $0.125$ & $0.300$ & $1$ & $0.231$ & $0.062$ & $0.182$ & $0.182$ & $0.111$ & $0.080$ & $0.278$ & $0.231$ & $0.125$ & $0.118$ & $0.091$ & $0.250$ & $0.100$ & $0.176$ & $0.143$ & $0.050$ & $0.095$ & $0.182$ & $0.300$ & $0.179$ & $0.077$ \\ 
Cyprus & $0.133$ & $0.176$ & $0.250$ & $0.231$ & $1$ & $0.056$ & $0.071$ & $0.071$ & $0.106$ & $0.115$ & $0.389$ & $0.200$ & $0.100$ & $0.143$ & $0.077$ & $0.091$ & $0.083$ & $0.100$ & $0.059$ & $0.095$ & $0.042$ & $0.154$ & $0.154$ & $0.094$ & $0.067$ \\ 
Czech Republic & $0.125$ & $0.235$ & $0.067$ & $0.062$ & $0.056$ & $1$ & $0.143$ & $0.143$ & $0.152$ & $0.364$ & $0.040$ & $0.188$ & $0.091$ & $0.139$ & $0.154$ & $0.083$ & $0.167$ & $0.438$ & $0.118$ & $0.091$ & $0.130$ & $0.143$ & $0.143$ & $0.241$ & $0.133$ \\ 
Estonia & $0.167$ & $0.133$ & $0.200$ & $0.182$ & $0.071$ & $0.143$ & $1$ & $0.500$ & $0.140$ & $0.040$ & $0.048$ & $0.154$ & $0$ & $0.088$ & $0.571$ & $0.286$ & $0.250$ & $0.188$ & $0.250$ & $0.053$ & $0.158$ & $0.091$ & $0.091$ & $0.103$ & $0.083$ \\ 
Finlandia & $0.077$ & $0.214$ & $0.200$ & $0.182$ & $0.071$ & $0.143$ & $0.500$ & $1$ & $0.140$ & $0.083$ & $0.048$ & $0.154$ & $0$ & $0.121$ & $0.375$ & $0.286$ & $0.250$ & $0.357$ & $0.364$ & $0.111$ & $0.100$ & $0.091$ & $0.091$ & $0.143$ & $0.083$ \\ 
France & $0.133$ & $0.227$ & $0.114$ & $0.111$ & $0.106$ & $0.152$ & $0.140$ & $0.140$ & $1$ & $0.370$ & $0.113$ & $0.130$ & $0.023$ & $0.396$ & $0.091$ & $0.070$ & $0.093$ & $0.244$ & $0.130$ & $0.163$ & $0.283$ & $0.089$ & $0.114$ & $0.408$ & $0.163$ \\ 
Germany & $0.167$ & $0.240$ & $0.083$ & $0.080$ & $0.115$ & $0.364$ & $0.040$ & $0.083$ & $0.370$ & $1$ & $0.091$ & $0.160$ & $0.048$ & $0.244$ & $0.042$ & $0.095$ & $0.143$ & $0.375$ & $0.160$ & $0.214$ & $0.241$ & $0.130$ & $0.238$ & $0.353$ & $0.125$ \\ 
Greece & $0.143$ & $0.125$ & $0.222$ & $0.278$ & $0.389$ & $0.040$ & $0.048$ & $0.048$ & $0.113$ & $0.091$ & $1$ & $0.136$ & $0.059$ & $0.237$ & $0.105$ & $0.056$ & $0.053$ & $0.115$ & $0.136$ & $0.154$ & $0.143$ & $0.158$ & $0.100$ & $0.105$ & $0.045$ \\ 
Hungary & $0.214$ & $0.250$ & $0.154$ & $0.231$ & $0.200$ & $0.188$ & $0.154$ & $0.154$ & $0.130$ & $0.160$ & $0.136$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0.081$ & $0.167$ & $0.091$ & $0.083$ & $0.222$ & $0.286$ & $0.095$ & $0.087$ & $0.154$ & $0.364$ & $0.167$ & $0.143$ \\ 
Ireland & $0.111$ & $0.083$ & $0.143$ & $0.125$ & $0.100$ & $0.091$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0.023$ & $0.048$ & $0.059$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0.065$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0.200$ & $0.071$ & $0$ & $0.067$ & $0.059$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0.077$ & $0.125$ \\ 
Italy & $0.182$ & $0.167$ & $0.121$ & $0.118$ & $0.143$ & $0.139$ & $0.088$ & $0.121$ & $0.396$ & $0.244$ & $0.237$ & $0.081$ & $0.065$ & $1$ & $0.059$ & $0.030$ & $0.094$ & $0.158$ & $0.111$ & $0.216$ & $0.175$ & $0.156$ & $0.057$ & $0.267$ & $0.056$ \\ 
Latvia & $0.083$ & $0.231$ & $0.222$ & $0.091$ & $0.077$ & $0.154$ & $0.571$ & $0.375$ & $0.091$ & $0.042$ & $0.105$ & $0.167$ & $0$ & $0.059$ & $1$ & $0.143$ & $0.286$ & $0.200$ & $0.273$ & $0.118$ & $0.167$ & $0.100$ & $0.100$ & $0.069$ & $0.091$ \\ 
Lithuania & $0.222$ & $0.077$ & $0.125$ & $0.250$ & $0.091$ & $0.083$ & $0.286$ & $0.286$ & $0.070$ & $0.095$ & $0.056$ & $0.091$ & $0$ & $0.030$ & $0.143$ & $1$ & $0.400$ & $0.231$ & $0.200$ & $0.062$ & $0.188$ & $0.125$ & $0.125$ & $0.115$ & $0.111$ \\ 
Luxembourg & $0.333$ & $0.154$ & $0.250$ & $0.100$ & $0.083$ & $0.167$ & $0.250$ & $0.250$ & $0.093$ & $0.143$ & $0.053$ & $0.083$ & $0.200$ & $0.094$ & $0.286$ & $0.400$ & $1$ & $0.214$ & $0.083$ & $0.125$ & $0.176$ & $0.111$ & $0.111$ & $0.111$ & $0.222$ \\ 
Netherlands & $0.167$ & $0.412$ & $0.118$ & $0.176$ & $0.100$ & $0.438$ & $0.188$ & $0.357$ & $0.244$ & $0.375$ & $0.115$ & $0.222$ & $0.071$ & $0.158$ & $0.200$ & $0.231$ & $0.214$ & $1$ & $0.294$ & $0.174$ & $0.261$ & $0.188$ & $0.188$ & $0.345$ & $0.111$ \\ 
Poland & $0.133$ & $0.250$ & $0.071$ & $0.143$ & $0.059$ & $0.118$ & $0.250$ & $0.364$ & $0.130$ & $0.160$ & $0.136$ & $0.286$ & $0$ & $0.111$ & $0.273$ & $0.200$ & $0.083$ & $0.294$ & $1$ & $0.278$ & $0.190$ & $0.071$ & $0.154$ & $0.094$ & $0.067$ \\ 
Portugal & $0.222$ & $0.190$ & $0.053$ & $0.050$ & $0.095$ & $0.091$ & $0.053$ & $0.111$ & $0.163$ & $0.214$ & $0.154$ & $0.095$ & $0.067$ & $0.216$ & $0.118$ & $0.062$ & $0.125$ & $0.174$ & $0.278$ & $1$ & $0.250$ & $0.053$ & $0.111$ & $0.290$ & $0.167$ \\ 
Romania & $0.200$ & $0.174$ & $0.100$ & $0.095$ & $0.042$ & $0.130$ & $0.158$ & $0.100$ & $0.283$ & $0.241$ & $0.143$ & $0.087$ & $0.059$ & $0.175$ & $0.167$ & $0.188$ & $0.176$ & $0.261$ & $0.190$ & $0.250$ & $1$ & $0.100$ & $0.100$ & $0.235$ & $0.150$ \\ 
Slovakia & $0.077$ & $0.133$ & $0.200$ & $0.182$ & $0.154$ & $0.143$ & $0.091$ & $0.091$ & $0.089$ & $0.130$ & $0.158$ & $0.154$ & $0$ & $0.156$ & $0.100$ & $0.125$ & $0.111$ & $0.188$ & $0.071$ & $0.053$ & $0.100$ & $1$ & $0.200$ & $0.143$ & $0.182$ \\ 
Slovenia & $0.167$ & $0.133$ & $0.200$ & $0.300$ & $0.154$ & $0.143$ & $0.091$ & $0.091$ & $0.114$ & $0.238$ & $0.100$ & $0.364$ & $0$ & $0.057$ & $0.100$ & $0.125$ & $0.111$ & $0.188$ & $0.154$ & $0.111$ & $0.100$ & $0.200$ & $1$ & $0.103$ & $0.083$ \\ 
Spain & $0.133$ & $0.276$ & $0.103$ & $0.179$ & $0.094$ & $0.241$ & $0.103$ & $0.143$ & $0.408$ & $0.353$ & $0.105$ & $0.167$ & $0.077$ & $0.267$ & $0.069$ & $0.115$ & $0.111$ & $0.345$ & $0.094$ & $0.290$ & $0.235$ & $0.143$ & $0.103$ & $1$ & $0.222$ \\ 
Sweden & $0.154$ & $0.200$ & $0.083$ & $0.077$ & $0.067$ & $0.133$ & $0.083$ & $0.083$ & $0.163$ & $0.125$ & $0.045$ & $0.143$ & $0.125$ & $0.056$ & $0.091$ & $0.111$ & $0.222$ & $0.111$ & $0.067$ & $0.167$ & $0.150$ & $0.182$ & $0.083$ & $0.222$ & $1$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Please do not post snippets, make your code compilable. Also, have you read and tried the suggestions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options ?

Comment: Also, `longtable` is for tables that splits on several pages. I changed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

If you reduce a size of all columns, the table can fit the page. Headings are main culprits here because their long country names takes most of the space. In the example below, I have used alphabet letters with annotation of what each letter represents.

Additionally, numbers can be formatted to maximum 2 significant digits. This way the width of all columns could be further reduced. Unfortunately, it seems table also needs a smaller font size, which I change to `\scriptsize`. you could try to change it to `\footnotesize` but it seems numbers get too tight.

Finally, an alternative approach to `landscape` is `sidewaystable`. It only rotates the content without changing a page layout, which sometimes is more preferable.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 2,
  table-format=1.2,
  minimum-decimal-digits = 1,
}


\begin{document}
% \begin{landscape}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \scriptsize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \centering
  \caption{}\vspace{6pt}
  \label{}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
    @{\hspace{0.7em}} c @{\hspace{0.7em}} |
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{25}{S}
    }
    & {A}   & {B}   & {C}   & {D}   & {E}   & {F}   & {G}   & {H}   & {I}   & {J}   & {K}   & {L}   & {M}   & {N}   & {O}   & {P}   & {Q}   & {R}   & {S}   & {T}   & {U}   & {V}   & {W}   & {X}   & {Y} \\
    \hline
    {A} & {1}   & 0.118 & 0.077 & 0.250 & 0.133 & 0.125 & 0.167 & 0.077 & 0.133 & 0.167 & 0.143 & 0.214 & 0.111 & 0.182 & 0.083 & 0.222 & 0.333 & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.222 & 0.200 & 0.077 & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.154 \\ 
    {B} & 0.118 & {1}   & 0.133 & 0.125 & 0.176 & 0.235 & 0.133 & 0.214 & 0.227 & 0.240 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.083 & 0.167 & 0.231 & 0.077 & 0.154 & 0.412 & 0.250 & 0.190 & 0.174 & 0.133 & 0.133 & 0.276 & 0.200 \\ 
    {C} & 0.077 & 0.133 & {1}   & 0.300 & 0.250 & 0.067 & 0.200 & 0.200 & 0.114 & 0.083 & 0.222 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.121 & 0.222 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.118 & 0.071 & 0.053 & 0.100 & 0.200 & 0.200 & 0.103 & 0.083 \\ 
    {D} & 0.250 & 0.125 & 0.300 & {1}   & 0.231 & 0.062 & 0.182 & 0.182 & 0.111 & 0.080 & 0.278 & 0.231 & 0.125 & 0.118 & 0.091 & 0.250 & 0.100 & 0.176 & 0.143 & 0.050 & 0.095 & 0.182 & 0.300 & 0.179 & 0.077 \\ 
    {E} & 0.133 & 0.176 & 0.250 & 0.231 & {1}   & 0.056 & 0.071 & 0.071 & 0.106 & 0.115 & 0.389 & 0.200 & 0.100 & 0.143 & 0.077 & 0.091 & 0.083 & 0.100 & 0.059 & 0.095 & 0.042 & 0.154 & 0.154 & 0.094 & 0.067 \\ 
    {F} & 0.125 & 0.235 & 0.067 & 0.062 & 0.056 & {1}   & 0.143 & 0.143 & 0.152 & 0.364 & 0.040 & 0.188 & 0.091 & 0.139 & 0.154 & 0.083 & 0.167 & 0.438 & 0.118 & 0.091 & 0.130 & 0.143 & 0.143 & 0.241 & 0.133 \\ 
    {G} & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.200 & 0.182 & 0.071 & 0.143 & {1}   & 0.500 & 0.140 & 0.040 & 0.048 & 0.154 & 0     & 0.088 & 0.571 & 0.286 & 0.250 & 0.188 & 0.250 & 0.053 & 0.158 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.103 & 0.083 \\ 
    {H} & 0.077 & 0.214 & 0.200 & 0.182 & 0.071 & 0.143 & 0.500 & {1}   & 0.140 & 0.083 & 0.048 & 0.154 & 0     & 0.121 & 0.375 & 0.286 & 0.250 & 0.357 & 0.364 & 0.111 & 0.100 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.143 & 0.083 \\ 
    {I} & 0.133 & 0.227 & 0.114 & 0.111 & 0.106 & 0.152 & 0.140 & 0.140 & {1}   & 0.370 & 0.113 & 0.130 & 0.023 & 0.396 & 0.091 & 0.070 & 0.093 & 0.244 & 0.130 & 0.163 & 0.283 & 0.089 & 0.114 & 0.408 & 0.163 \\ 
    {J} & 0.167 & 0.240 & 0.083 & 0.080 & 0.115 & 0.364 & 0.040 & 0.083 & 0.370 & {1}   & 0.091 & 0.160 & 0.048 & 0.244 & 0.042 & 0.095 & 0.143 & 0.375 & 0.160 & 0.214 & 0.241 & 0.130 & 0.238 & 0.353 & 0.125 \\ 
    {K} & 0.143 & 0.125 & 0.222 & 0.278 & 0.389 & 0.040 & 0.048 & 0.048 & 0.113 & 0.091 & {1}   & 0.136 & 0.059 & 0.237 & 0.105 & 0.056 & 0.053 & 0.115 & 0.136 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.158 & 0.100 & 0.105 & 0.045 \\ 
    {L} & 0.214 & 0.250 & 0.154 & 0.231 & 0.200 & 0.188 & 0.154 & 0.154 & 0.130 & 0.160 & 0.136 & {1}   & 0     & 0.081 & 0.167 & 0.091 & 0.083 & 0.222 & 0.286 & 0.095 & 0.087 & 0.154 & 0.364 & 0.167 & 0.143 \\ 
    {M} & 0.111 & 0.083 & 0.143 & 0.125 & 0.100 & 0.091 & 0     & 0     & 0.023 & 0.048 & 0.059 & 0     & {1}   & 0.065 & 0     & 0     & 0.200 & 0.071 & 0     & 0.067 & 0.059 & 0     & 0     & 0.077 & 0.125 \\ 
    {N} & 0.182 & 0.167 & 0.121 & 0.118 & 0.143 & 0.139 & 0.088 & 0.121 & 0.396 & 0.244 & 0.237 & 0.081 & 0.065 & {1}   & 0.059 & 0.030 & 0.094 & 0.158 & 0.111 & 0.216 & 0.175 & 0.156 & 0.057 & 0.267 & 0.056 \\ 
    {O} & 0.083 & 0.231 & 0.222 & 0.091 & 0.077 & 0.154 & 0.571 & 0.375 & 0.091 & 0.042 & 0.105 & 0.167 & 0     & 0.059 & {1}   & 0.143 & 0.286 & 0.200 & 0.273 & 0.118 & 0.167 & 0.100 & 0.100 & 0.069 & 0.091 \\ 
    {P} & 0.222 & 0.077 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.091 & 0.083 & 0.286 & 0.286 & 0.070 & 0.095 & 0.056 & 0.091 & 0     & 0.030 & 0.143 & {1}   & 0.400 & 0.231 & 0.200 & 0.062 & 0.188 & 0.125 & 0.125 & 0.115 & 0.111 \\ 
    {Q} & 0.333 & 0.154 & 0.250 & 0.100 & 0.083 & 0.167 & 0.250 & 0.250 & 0.093 & 0.143 & 0.053 & 0.083 & 0.200 & 0.094 & 0.286 & 0.400 & {1}   & 0.214 & 0.083 & 0.125 & 0.176 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.222 \\ 
    {R} & 0.167 & 0.412 & 0.118 & 0.176 & 0.100 & 0.438 & 0.188 & 0.357 & 0.244 & 0.375 & 0.115 & 0.222 & 0.071 & 0.158 & 0.200 & 0.231 & 0.214 & {1}   & 0.294 & 0.174 & 0.261 & 0.188 & 0.188 & 0.345 & 0.111 \\ 
    {S} & 0.133 & 0.250 & 0.071 & 0.143 & 0.059 & 0.118 & 0.250 & 0.364 & 0.130 & 0.160 & 0.136 & 0.286 & 0     & 0.111 & 0.273 & 0.200 & 0.083 & 0.294 & {1}   & 0.278 & 0.190 & 0.071 & 0.154 & 0.094 & 0.067 \\ 
    {T} & 0.222 & 0.190 & 0.053 & 0.050 & 0.095 & 0.091 & 0.053 & 0.111 & 0.163 & 0.214 & 0.154 & 0.095 & 0.067 & 0.216 & 0.118 & 0.062 & 0.125 & 0.174 & 0.278 & {1}   & 0.250 & 0.053 & 0.111 & 0.290 & 0.167 \\ 
    {U} & 0.200 & 0.174 & 0.100 & 0.095 & 0.042 & 0.130 & 0.158 & 0.100 & 0.283 & 0.241 & 0.143 & 0.087 & 0.059 & 0.175 & 0.167 & 0.188 & 0.176 & 0.261 & 0.190 & 0.250 & {1}   & 0.100 & 0.100 & 0.235 & 0.150 \\ 
    {V} & 0.077 & 0.133 & 0.200 & 0.182 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.089 & 0.130 & 0.158 & 0.154 & 0     & 0.156 & 0.100 & 0.125 & 0.111 & 0.188 & 0.071 & 0.053 & 0.100 & {1}   & 0.200 & 0.143 & 0.182 \\ 
    {W} & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.200 & 0.300 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.114 & 0.238 & 0.100 & 0.364 & 0     & 0.057 & 0.100 & 0.125 & 0.111 & 0.188 & 0.154 & 0.111 & 0.100 & 0.200 & {1}   & 0.103 & 0.083 \\ 
    {X} & 0.133 & 0.276 & 0.103 & 0.179 & 0.094 & 0.241 & 0.103 & 0.143 & 0.408 & 0.353 & 0.105 & 0.167 & 0.077 & 0.267 & 0.069 & 0.115 & 0.111 & 0.345 & 0.094 & 0.290 & 0.235 & 0.143 & 0.103 & {1}   & 0.222 \\ 
    {Y} & 0.154 & 0.200 & 0.083 & 0.077 & 0.067 & 0.133 & 0.083 & 0.083 & 0.163 & 0.125 & 0.045 & 0.143 & 0.125 & 0.056 & 0.091 & 0.111 & 0.222 & 0.111 & 0.067 & 0.167 & 0.150 & 0.182 & 0.083 & 0.222 & {1} \\ 
    \hline
  \end{tabular*}
  \par\vspace{3pt}\parbox{\linewidth}{%
    A:~Austria,
    B:~Belgium,
    C:~Bulgaria,
    D:~Croatia,
    E:~Cyprus,
    F:~Czech Republic,
    G:~Estonia,
    H:~Finland,
    I:~France,
    J:~Germany,
    K:~Greece,
    L:~Hungary,
    M:~Ireland,
    N:~Italy,
    O:~Latvia,
    P:~Lithuania,
    Q:~Luxembourg,
    R:~Netherlands,
    S:~Poland,
    T:~Portugal,
    U:~Romania,
    V:~Slovakia,
    W:~Slovenia,
    X:~Spain,
    Y:~Sweden
  }
\end{sidewaystable}
% \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this looks wonderful! Much appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: The titles will fit on the top using \rotatebox, and you may have room for one wide column in landscape.  I know examples exist on this site, but I can't find any.

Comment: @Alekin You welcome.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I thought about rotated titles but it's rejected most of the times I suggest it.

Answer (score 2):

Since I couldn't find any examples of rotated titles, I added one.  Most of the code was stolen from Celdor's solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 2,
  table-format=1.2,
  minimum-decimal-digits = 1,
}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
% \begin{landscape}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \scriptsize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \centering
  \caption{}\vspace{6pt}
  \label{}
  \def\Rtext#1{\rotatebox{-90}{#1}}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
    @{\hspace{0.7em}} r @{\hspace{0.7em}} |
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{25}{S}
    }
    & \Rtext{Austria} & \Rtext{Belgium} & \Rtext{Bulgaria} & \Rtext{Croatia} & \Rtext{Cyprus} & \Rtext{Czech Republic} & \Rtext{Estonia} & \Rtext{Finland} & \Rtext{France} & \Rtext{Germany} & \Rtext{Greece} & \Rtext{Hungary} & \Rtext{Ireland} & \Rtext{Italy} & \Rtext{Latvia} & \Rtext{Lithuania} & \Rtext{Luxembourg} & \Rtext{Netherlands} & \Rtext{Poland} & \Rtext{Portugal} & \Rtext{Romania} & \Rtext{Slovakia} & \Rtext{Slovenia} & \Rtext{Spain} & \Rtext{Sweden} \\
    \hline
    Austria & {1}   & 0.118 & 0.077 & 0.250 & 0.133 & 0.125 & 0.167 & 0.077 & 0.133 & 0.167 & 0.143 & 0.214 & 0.111 & 0.182 & 0.083 & 0.222 & 0.333 & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.222 & 0.200 & 0.077 & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.154 \\ 
    Belgium & 0.118 & {1}   & 0.133 & 0.125 & 0.176 & 0.235 & 0.133 & 0.214 & 0.227 & 0.240 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.083 & 0.167 & 0.231 & 0.077 & 0.154 & 0.412 & 0.250 & 0.190 & 0.174 & 0.133 & 0.133 & 0.276 & 0.200 \\ 
   Bulgaria & 0.077 & 0.133 & {1}   & 0.300 & 0.250 & 0.067 & 0.200 & 0.200 & 0.114 & 0.083 & 0.222 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.121 & 0.222 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.118 & 0.071 & 0.053 & 0.100 & 0.200 & 0.200 & 0.103 & 0.083 \\ 
    Croatia & 0.250 & 0.125 & 0.300 & {1}   & 0.231 & 0.062 & 0.182 & 0.182 & 0.111 & 0.080 & 0.278 & 0.231 & 0.125 & 0.118 & 0.091 & 0.250 & 0.100 & 0.176 & 0.143 & 0.050 & 0.095 & 0.182 & 0.300 & 0.179 & 0.077 \\ 
    Cyprus & 0.133 & 0.176 & 0.250 & 0.231 & {1}   & 0.056 & 0.071 & 0.071 & 0.106 & 0.115 & 0.389 & 0.200 & 0.100 & 0.143 & 0.077 & 0.091 & 0.083 & 0.100 & 0.059 & 0.095 & 0.042 & 0.154 & 0.154 & 0.094 & 0.067 \\ 
    Czech Republic & 0.125 & 0.235 & 0.067 & 0.062 & 0.056 & {1}   & 0.143 & 0.143 & 0.152 & 0.364 & 0.040 & 0.188 & 0.091 & 0.139 & 0.154 & 0.083 & 0.167 & 0.438 & 0.118 & 0.091 & 0.130 & 0.143 & 0.143 & 0.241 & 0.133 \\ 
    Estonia & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.200 & 0.182 & 0.071 & 0.143 & {1}   & 0.500 & 0.140 & 0.040 & 0.048 & 0.154 & 0     & 0.088 & 0.571 & 0.286 & 0.250 & 0.188 & 0.250 & 0.053 & 0.158 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.103 & 0.083 \\ 
    Finland & 0.077 & 0.214 & 0.200 & 0.182 & 0.071 & 0.143 & 0.500 & {1}   & 0.140 & 0.083 & 0.048 & 0.154 & 0     & 0.121 & 0.375 & 0.286 & 0.250 & 0.357 & 0.364 & 0.111 & 0.100 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.143 & 0.083 \\ 
    France & 0.133 & 0.227 & 0.114 & 0.111 & 0.106 & 0.152 & 0.140 & 0.140 & {1}   & 0.370 & 0.113 & 0.130 & 0.023 & 0.396 & 0.091 & 0.070 & 0.093 & 0.244 & 0.130 & 0.163 & 0.283 & 0.089 & 0.114 & 0.408 & 0.163 \\ 
    Germany & 0.167 & 0.240 & 0.083 & 0.080 & 0.115 & 0.364 & 0.040 & 0.083 & 0.370 & {1}   & 0.091 & 0.160 & 0.048 & 0.244 & 0.042 & 0.095 & 0.143 & 0.375 & 0.160 & 0.214 & 0.241 & 0.130 & 0.238 & 0.353 & 0.125 \\ 
    Greece & 0.143 & 0.125 & 0.222 & 0.278 & 0.389 & 0.040 & 0.048 & 0.048 & 0.113 & 0.091 & {1}   & 0.136 & 0.059 & 0.237 & 0.105 & 0.056 & 0.053 & 0.115 & 0.136 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.158 & 0.100 & 0.105 & 0.045 \\ 
    Hungary & 0.214 & 0.250 & 0.154 & 0.231 & 0.200 & 0.188 & 0.154 & 0.154 & 0.130 & 0.160 & 0.136 & {1}   & 0     & 0.081 & 0.167 & 0.091 & 0.083 & 0.222 & 0.286 & 0.095 & 0.087 & 0.154 & 0.364 & 0.167 & 0.143 \\ 
    Ireland & 0.111 & 0.083 & 0.143 & 0.125 & 0.100 & 0.091 & 0     & 0     & 0.023 & 0.048 & 0.059 & 0     & {1}   & 0.065 & 0     & 0     & 0.200 & 0.071 & 0     & 0.067 & 0.059 & 0     & 0     & 0.077 & 0.125 \\ 
    Italy & 0.182 & 0.167 & 0.121 & 0.118 & 0.143 & 0.139 & 0.088 & 0.121 & 0.396 & 0.244 & 0.237 & 0.081 & 0.065 & {1}   & 0.059 & 0.030 & 0.094 & 0.158 & 0.111 & 0.216 & 0.175 & 0.156 & 0.057 & 0.267 & 0.056 \\ 
    Latvia & 0.083 & 0.231 & 0.222 & 0.091 & 0.077 & 0.154 & 0.571 & 0.375 & 0.091 & 0.042 & 0.105 & 0.167 & 0     & 0.059 & {1}   & 0.143 & 0.286 & 0.200 & 0.273 & 0.118 & 0.167 & 0.100 & 0.100 & 0.069 & 0.091 \\ 
    Lithuania & 0.222 & 0.077 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.091 & 0.083 & 0.286 & 0.286 & 0.070 & 0.095 & 0.056 & 0.091 & 0     & 0.030 & 0.143 & {1}   & 0.400 & 0.231 & 0.200 & 0.062 & 0.188 & 0.125 & 0.125 & 0.115 & 0.111 \\ 
    Luxembourg & 0.333 & 0.154 & 0.250 & 0.100 & 0.083 & 0.167 & 0.250 & 0.250 & 0.093 & 0.143 & 0.053 & 0.083 & 0.200 & 0.094 & 0.286 & 0.400 & {1}   & 0.214 & 0.083 & 0.125 & 0.176 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.222 \\ 
    Netherlands & 0.167 & 0.412 & 0.118 & 0.176 & 0.100 & 0.438 & 0.188 & 0.357 & 0.244 & 0.375 & 0.115 & 0.222 & 0.071 & 0.158 & 0.200 & 0.231 & 0.214 & {1}   & 0.294 & 0.174 & 0.261 & 0.188 & 0.188 & 0.345 & 0.111 \\ 
    Poland & 0.133 & 0.250 & 0.071 & 0.143 & 0.059 & 0.118 & 0.250 & 0.364 & 0.130 & 0.160 & 0.136 & 0.286 & 0     & 0.111 & 0.273 & 0.200 & 0.083 & 0.294 & {1}   & 0.278 & 0.190 & 0.071 & 0.154 & 0.094 & 0.067 \\ 
    Portugal & 0.222 & 0.190 & 0.053 & 0.050 & 0.095 & 0.091 & 0.053 & 0.111 & 0.163 & 0.214 & 0.154 & 0.095 & 0.067 & 0.216 & 0.118 & 0.062 & 0.125 & 0.174 & 0.278 & {1}   & 0.250 & 0.053 & 0.111 & 0.290 & 0.167 \\ 
    Romania & 0.200 & 0.174 & 0.100 & 0.095 & 0.042 & 0.130 & 0.158 & 0.100 & 0.283 & 0.241 & 0.143 & 0.087 & 0.059 & 0.175 & 0.167 & 0.188 & 0.176 & 0.261 & 0.190 & 0.250 & {1}   & 0.100 & 0.100 & 0.235 & 0.150 \\ 
    Slovakia & 0.077 & 0.133 & 0.200 & 0.182 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.089 & 0.130 & 0.158 & 0.154 & 0     & 0.156 & 0.100 & 0.125 & 0.111 & 0.188 & 0.071 & 0.053 & 0.100 & {1}   & 0.200 & 0.143 & 0.182 \\ 
    Slovenia & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.200 & 0.300 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.114 & 0.238 & 0.100 & 0.364 & 0     & 0.057 & 0.100 & 0.125 & 0.111 & 0.188 & 0.154 & 0.111 & 0.100 & 0.200 & {1}   & 0.103 & 0.083 \\ 
    Spain & 0.133 & 0.276 & 0.103 & 0.179 & 0.094 & 0.241 & 0.103 & 0.143 & 0.408 & 0.353 & 0.105 & 0.167 & 0.077 & 0.267 & 0.069 & 0.115 & 0.111 & 0.345 & 0.094 & 0.290 & 0.235 & 0.143 & 0.103 & {1}   & 0.222 \\ 
    Sweden & 0.154 & 0.200 & 0.083 & 0.077 & 0.067 & 0.133 & 0.083 & 0.083 & 0.163 & 0.125 & 0.045 & 0.143 & 0.125 & 0.056 & 0.091 & 0.111 & 0.222 & 0.111 & 0.067 & 0.167 & 0.150 & 0.182 & 0.083 & 0.222 & {1} \\ 
    \hline
  \end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
% \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Celdor, but with two-letter country codes (the final part, with the correspondence, could even be omitted).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l*{25}{S[table-format=1.3]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {AT} & {BE} & {BG} & {HR} & {CY} & {CZ} & {EE} & {FI} & {FR} & {DE} & {GR} & {HU} & {IE}
& {IT} & {LV} & {LT} & {LU} & {NL} & {PL} & {PT} & {RO} & {SK} & {SI} & {ES} & {SE} \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
AT & 1     & 0.118 & 0.077 & 0.250 & 0.133 & 0.125 & 0.167 & 0.077 & 0.133 & 0.167 & 0.143 & 0.214 & 0.111 & 0.182 & 0.083 & 0.222 & 0.333 & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.222 & 0.200 & 0.077 & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.154 \\ 
BE & 0.118 & 1     & 0.133 & 0.125 & 0.176 & 0.235 & 0.133 & 0.214 & 0.227 & 0.240 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.083 & 0.167 & 0.231 & 0.077 & 0.154 & 0.412 & 0.250 & 0.190 & 0.174 & 0.133 & 0.133 & 0.276 & 0.200 \\ 
BG & 0.077 & 0.133 & 1     & 0.300 & 0.250 & 0.067 & 0.200 & 0.200 & 0.114 & 0.083 & 0.222 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.121 & 0.222 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.118 & 0.071 & 0.053 & 0.100 & 0.200 & 0.200 & 0.103 & 0.083 \\ 
HR & 0.250 & 0.125 & 0.300 & 1     & 0.231 & 0.062 & 0.182 & 0.182 & 0.111 & 0.080 & 0.278 & 0.231 & 0.125 & 0.118 & 0.091 & 0.250 & 0.100 & 0.176 & 0.143 & 0.050 & 0.095 & 0.182 & 0.300 & 0.179 & 0.077 \\ 
CY & 0.133 & 0.176 & 0.250 & 0.231 & 1     & 0.056 & 0.071 & 0.071 & 0.106 & 0.115 & 0.389 & 0.200 & 0.100 & 0.143 & 0.077 & 0.091 & 0.083 & 0.100 & 0.059 & 0.095 & 0.042 & 0.154 & 0.154 & 0.094 & 0.067 \\ 
CZ & 0.125 & 0.235 & 0.067 & 0.062 & 0.056 & 1     & 0.143 & 0.143 & 0.152 & 0.364 & 0.040 & 0.188 & 0.091 & 0.139 & 0.154 & 0.083 & 0.167 & 0.438 & 0.118 & 0.091 & 0.130 & 0.143 & 0.143 & 0.241 & 0.133 \\ 
EE & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.200 & 0.182 & 0.071 & 0.143 & 1     & 0.500 & 0.140 & 0.040 & 0.048 & 0.154 & 0 & 0.088 & 0.571 & 0.286 & 0.250 & 0.188 & 0.250 & 0.053 & 0.158 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.103 & 0.083 \\ 
FI & 0.077 & 0.214 & 0.200 & 0.182 & 0.071 & 0.143 & 0.500 & 1     & 0.140 & 0.083 & 0.048 & 0.154 & 0 & 0.121 & 0.375 & 0.286 & 0.250 & 0.357 & 0.364 & 0.111 & 0.100 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.143 & 0.083 \\ 
FR & 0.133 & 0.227 & 0.114 & 0.111 & 0.106 & 0.152 & 0.140 & 0.140 & 1     & 0.370 & 0.113 & 0.130 & 0.023 & 0.396 & 0.091 & 0.070 & 0.093 & 0.244 & 0.130 & 0.163 & 0.283 & 0.089 & 0.114 & 0.408 & 0.163 \\ 
DE & 0.167 & 0.240 & 0.083 & 0.080 & 0.115 & 0.364 & 0.040 & 0.083 & 0.370 & 1     & 0.091 & 0.160 & 0.048 & 0.244 & 0.042 & 0.095 & 0.143 & 0.375 & 0.160 & 0.214 & 0.241 & 0.130 & 0.238 & 0.353 & 0.125 \\ 
GR & 0.143 & 0.125 & 0.222 & 0.278 & 0.389 & 0.040 & 0.048 & 0.048 & 0.113 & 0.091 & 1     & 0.136 & 0.059 & 0.237 & 0.105 & 0.056 & 0.053 & 0.115 & 0.136 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.158 & 0.100 & 0.105 & 0.045 \\ 
HU & 0.214 & 0.250 & 0.154 & 0.231 & 0.200 & 0.188 & 0.154 & 0.154 & 0.130 & 0.160 & 0.136 & 1     & 0 & 0.081 & 0.167 & 0.091 & 0.083 & 0.222 & 0.286 & 0.095 & 0.087 & 0.154 & 0.364 & 0.167 & 0.143 \\ 
IE & 0.111 & 0.083 & 0.143 & 0.125 & 0.100 & 0.091 & 0 & 0 & 0.023 & 0.048 & 0.059 & 0     & 1     & 0.065 & 0 & 0 & 0.200 & 0.071 & 0 & 0.067 & 0.059 & 0 & 0 & 0.077 & 0.125 \\ 
IT & 0.182 & 0.167 & 0.121 & 0.118 & 0.143 & 0.139 & 0.088 & 0.121 & 0.396 & 0.244 & 0.237 & 0.081 & 0.065 & 1     & 0.059 & 0.030 & 0.094 & 0.158 & 0.111 & 0.216 & 0.175 & 0.156 & 0.057 & 0.267 & 0.056 \\ 
LV & 0.083 & 0.231 & 0.222 & 0.091 & 0.077 & 0.154 & 0.571 & 0.375 & 0.091 & 0.042 & 0.105 & 0.167 & 0 & 0.059 & 1     & 0.143 & 0.286 & 0.200 & 0.273 & 0.118 & 0.167 & 0.100 & 0.100 & 0.069 & 0.091 \\ 
LT & 0.222 & 0.077 & 0.125 & 0.250 & 0.091 & 0.083 & 0.286 & 0.286 & 0.070 & 0.095 & 0.056 & 0.091 & 0 & 0.030 & 0.143 & 1     & 0.400 & 0.231 & 0.200 & 0.062 & 0.188 & 0.125 & 0.125 & 0.115 & 0.111 \\ 
LU & 0.333 & 0.154 & 0.250 & 0.100 & 0.083 & 0.167 & 0.250 & 0.250 & 0.093 & 0.143 & 0.053 & 0.083 & 0.200 & 0.094 & 0.286 & 0.400 & 1     & 0.214 & 0.083 & 0.125 & 0.176 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.222 \\ 
NL & 0.167 & 0.412 & 0.118 & 0.176 & 0.100 & 0.438 & 0.188 & 0.357 & 0.244 & 0.375 & 0.115 & 0.222 & 0.071 & 0.158 & 0.200 & 0.231 & 0.214 & 1     & 0.294 & 0.174 & 0.261 & 0.188 & 0.188 & 0.345 & 0.111 \\ 
PL & 0.133 & 0.250 & 0.071 & 0.143 & 0.059 & 0.118 & 0.250 & 0.364 & 0.130 & 0.160 & 0.136 & 0.286 & 0 & 0.111 & 0.273 & 0.200 & 0.083 & 0.294 & 1     & 0.278 & 0.190 & 0.071 & 0.154 & 0.094 & 0.067 \\ 
PT & 0.222 & 0.190 & 0.053 & 0.050 & 0.095 & 0.091 & 0.053 & 0.111 & 0.163 & 0.214 & 0.154 & 0.095 & 0.067 & 0.216 & 0.118 & 0.062 & 0.125 & 0.174 & 0.278 & 1     & 0.250 & 0.053 & 0.111 & 0.290 & 0.167 \\ 
RO & 0.200 & 0.174 & 0.100 & 0.095 & 0.042 & 0.130 & 0.158 & 0.100 & 0.283 & 0.241 & 0.143 & 0.087 & 0.059 & 0.175 & 0.167 & 0.188 & 0.176 & 0.261 & 0.190 & 0.250 & 1     & 0.100 & 0.100 & 0.235 & 0.150 \\ 
SK & 0.077 & 0.133 & 0.200 & 0.182 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.089 & 0.130 & 0.158 & 0.154 & 0 & 0.156 & 0.100 & 0.125 & 0.111 & 0.188 & 0.071 & 0.053 & 0.100 & 1     & 0.200 & 0.143 & 0.182 \\ 
SI & 0.167 & 0.133 & 0.200 & 0.300 & 0.154 & 0.143 & 0.091 & 0.091 & 0.114 & 0.238 & 0.100 & 0.364 & 0 & 0.057 & 0.100 & 0.125 & 0.111 & 0.188 & 0.154 & 0.111 & 0.100 & 0.200 & 1     & 0.103 & 0.083 \\ 
ES & 0.133 & 0.276 & 0.103 & 0.179 & 0.094 & 0.241 & 0.103 & 0.143 & 0.408 & 0.353 & 0.105 & 0.167 & 0.077 & 0.267 & 0.069 & 0.115 & 0.111 & 0.345 & 0.094 & 0.290 & 0.235 & 0.143 & 0.103 & 1     & 0.222 \\ 
SE & 0.154 & 0.200 & 0.083 & 0.077 & 0.067 & 0.133 & 0.083 & 0.083 & 0.163 & 0.125 & 0.045 & 0.143 & 0.125 & 0.056 & 0.091 & 0.111 & 0.222 & 0.111 & 0.067 & 0.167 & 0.150 & 0.182 & 0.083 & 0.222 & 1     \\ 
\midrule
\end{tabular*}

\begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth}}
  \footnotesize
  Countries:
  AT~Austria,
  BE~Belgium,
  BG~Bulgaria,
  HR~Croatia,
  CY~Cyprus,
  CZ~Czech Republic,
  EE~Estonia,
  FI~Finland,
  FR~France
  DE~Germany,
  GR~Greece,
  HU~Hungary,
  IE~Ireland,
  IT~Italy,
  LV~Latvia,
  LT~Lithuania,
  LU~Luxembourg,
  NL~Netherlands,
  PL~Poland,
  PT~Portugal,
  RO~Romania,
  SK~Slovakia,
  SI~Slovenia,
  ES~Spain,
  SE~Sweden
  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{A table with some data about some countries}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a good idea regarding the country codes. Why didn't I think about it in the first place.